# .NETFrameworkのCOM登録について

Tags: c#, visual-studio, com

ある.NetFramework4.0向けの　Visual Studio　のソリューションを
IDE上から実行しようとしたところ、

```
アセンブリ "XXX.dll" を登録できません - アクセスが拒否されました。管理者としてアプリケーションを実行しているか確認してください。レジストリ キー 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\XXX.XXXDef' へのアクセスが拒否されました
```

という、メッセージが出力され、ビルドに失敗しました(ビルドそのものは成功していて、COM登録に失敗したようですが)

このソリューションは
プロジェクト1(実行ファイル.exe)
プロジェクト2(関数集.dll)
という構成になっていて、
プロジェクト1がプロジェクト2を参照しています
管理者権限でVisualStudioを実行すればエラーは発生せずに実行できるし、他のマシンに
exeとdllをコピーすれば、Regsvr32でdllをわざわざ登録しなくても動作します

質問なのですがそもそも．NetFramework用のライブラリをCOM登録する意味はあるのでしょうか

Answer (score 2):

[.NETアセンブリ―をCOMオブジェクトとしてシミュレートさせる](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/f07c8z1c.aspx)ことで、.NET Framework以外で動作するCOMオブジェクトを参照可能な環境(例えばVBA)から.NETで実装したオブジェクトを使用することが可能になります。

またCOM相互運用の可否はプロジェクトのプロパティページの「ビルド」タブにある「COM相互運用機能の登録」で設定できます。

Answer (score 0):

プロジェクト2(関数集.dll) のプロジェクトの設定で「アセンブリを COM 参照可能にする」にチェックがついてたりしませんか？

※今手元でVisualStudioを起動出来ないので具体的な場所までは提示できません。すみません